# can't connect to the mysql server on '127.0.0.1'

Tags: mysql, navicat

I am trying to connect to the mysql in MAMP using navicat.

I read that in advance settings i need to set path of mysql.sock. 
But i couldn't locate this file in Application/MAMP/tmp/mysql.

**Questions :**

Do i have to set this path ?

Any reason why this is not located in this folder ?

If i try to connect without setting this path it gives me error "Can't connect to the mysql server on '127.0.0.1' ". What could be the reason behind this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem is with location of mytsql.sock. This will help you in fixing the issue http://fischerlaender.de/apple-mac/mac-os-x-trouble-with-mamp-mysql

Comment: this tutorial shows problem of path, but i don't even have that file in Application/MAMP/tmp/mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling MAMP Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Use this path:

/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock